# Dockerfile entrypoint with runtime args not working as expected

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I'm pretty new to Docker and I'm trying to Dockerize a particular tool that is difficult to run on different platforms. For some reason the ENTRYPOINT and CMD commands are not working as I would expect.

What is baffling me is that when I run a script from inside the container, the script works, but when I run what I think is the exact same thing passing in runtime arguments, I get a completely different response from the script.  I would expect them to be the same.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential flex bison

COPY . /unicornscan
WORKDIR /unicornscan

RUN patch src/unilib/tsc.c patches/unicornscan-0.4.7-gcc5.patch
RUN ./configure CFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-bundled-ltdl
RUN make
RUN make install

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/unicornscan"]
CMD []
```

When I remove the entrypoint and cmd from the dockerfile and then run:

```
docker run -it test/image:1.0 sh
```

I am in the container.  I then run:

```
/bin/sh -c "unicornscan -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a"
```

It starts telling me which ports are open on IP 22.22.22.22, which is what this tool is supposed to do.

Now, I add the entrypoint and cmd command back, rebuild, and then I run

```
docker run test/image:1.0 -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a
```

Now I get this output from the tool:

```
Send exiting ack, parent died?: system error No such file or directory
```

Every time I repeat this process the same thing happens, so my quesiton is, why? What is the difference between the two commands. I was under the impression that they were exactly the same.

Comment: Have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile/39408777#39408777

Answer (score 0):

`ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/unicornscan"]` executes `unicornscan` without bash, with PID 1 and allows it to receive signals like SIGTERM.

`/bin/sh -c "unicornscan -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a"` runs `unicornscan` as child process of `/bin/sh`.

I don't know anything abount `unicornscan`, but I'd try changing your `ENTRYPOINT` to `["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/unicornscan"]` and seeing what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but im unable to pass arguments to unicornscan.  I tried ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/unicornscan $options"] and then passing in -e options="-I -msf 22.22.22.22:a" and that actually works but its pretty ugly. Wondering if there is a best practice I'm missing.

Comment: Your original `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/unicornscan"]` is considered the best practice. That said, `unicornscan`might have some particularity that requires a hack. Why don't you create a public repo for that Docker image? It will be helpful to others and maybe one day someone can PR this issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future runs into this, this is how I solved it.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential flex bison

COPY . /unicornscan
WORKDIR /unicornscan

RUN patch src/unilib/tsc.c patches/unicornscan-0.4.7-gcc5.patch
RUN ./configure CFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-bundled-ltdl
RUN make
RUN make install
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/unicornscan/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD []
```

/unicornscan/entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
unicornscan "$@"
```

It turned out when I originally ran:

```
docker run test/image:1.0 -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a
```

It was interpreted as:

```
/bin/sh -c unicornscan -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a
```

With the wrapper script, it is now interpreted as:

```
/bin/sh -c "unicornscan -I -msf 22.22.22.22:a"
```